# how to change rows and columns of table based on select id option value?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the number of rows and columns of a html table with the input text, based on the value selected in the select Id option?
like 
Number of Models    : 1,2,3,4
Number of items per Model   :(this is the table that takes the input values and this needs to change the number of rows or columns of the table based on the value selected in the 'Number of Models'), this is the code i have:

```
      <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Number of Models:<title="Number of Models"></th>

<td><select id="numberofmodels" onkeyup="NumberOfModels()" name="Number of Models">

  <option >1</option >
  <option >2</option >
  <option >3</option >
  <option >4</option >
  <option >5</option >
  <option >6</option >
  </select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <th>Number of items per model:</th>
  <td>
  <table border="1">
       <tr>
      <td>
<input id="itemsmodel" onkeyup="ItemsModelValidate()" type="text" maxlength="50" >       <br>

</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```

can somebody give me the javascript function ItemsModelValidate() to make this work ?

I have the following javascript function for other purpose, can this be edited to achieve that ?

```
  function ItemsModelValidate(){
   $itemsmodel = document.getElementById("itemsmodel").value;
       if(!/^[0-9]+$/.test($itemsmodel)) {
           alert();
       } 
           } 
     function NumbersOfModels(){
   $numberofmodels = document.getElementById("numberofmodels").value;
       if(!/^[0-9]+$/.test($numberofmodels)) {
           alert();
       } 
           }
```

Comment: Can we have code please?

Comment: can you more specific?

Comment: SO rules 'forbid' us to give a complete answer, please show us what you got. And you are using spaces in the id of the select, that is not allowed in that attribute

Comment: that is what i have got, the table takes inputs and the number of rows and columns of the table 'depend' on the value selected in the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Number of Models:</th>
        <th>
            <select id="NumberOfModels" name="Number of Models">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
            </select>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Number of items per model:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tbody id="itemsmodel"></tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var  models = document.getElementById("NumberOfModels");
    var  modelsTable = document.getElementById("itemsmodel");

    models.addEventListener("change", drawModels, false);

    function drawModels(){
        var modelsNum = parseInt(models.value);
        var curModels = modelsTable.rows.length;
        if (modelsNum > curModels)  {
            var delta = modelsNum - curModels;
            for(var i = 0; i < delta; i++)  {
                var rowElement = document.createElement("tr");
                var cellElement = document.createElement("td");
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("maxlength", "3");
                input.addEventListener("keyup", drawItems, false);
                cellElement.appendChild(input);
                rowElement.appendChild(cellElement);
                modelsTable.appendChild(rowElement);
            }
        } else {
            while(modelsTable.rows.length > modelsNum){
                var row = modelsTable.rows[modelsTable.rows.length - 1];
                modelsTable.removeChild(row);
            }
        }
    }

    function drawItems(){
        var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var val = this.value;
        var isNum = /^\d+$/.test(val);
        if(isNum){
            var curCells = row.cells.length - 1;
            var cellsNum = parseInt(val);
            if(cellsNum > curCells){
                var delta = cellsNum - curCells;
                for(var i = 0; i < delta; i++)  {
                    var cellEl = document.createElement("td");
                    cellEl.innerText = "Lorem  ipsum";
                    row.appendChild(cellEl);
                }
            } else {
                while(row.cells.length > cellsNum + 1) {
                    var cell = row.cells[row.cells.length-1];
                    row.removeChild(cell);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    drawModels();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I select the 'number of models' as 2, the table size of 'number of items per model' should increase number of rows and/or columns to 2 to accomodate input, but that is happening with the above code, the number of rows/ columns are remaining the same even when i select a different option.